# How can I convert these time-stamps into its components?

Tags: r

I have this kind of data in R and I would like to extract the year, month, day etc.

```
19620101
19620102
```

I am able to decompose the month and day, but the year and month is not giving me the right answer. Can you please tell me why?

```
df$year <- format(as.Date(df$DATE),'%Y')
df$month <- format(as.Date(df$DATE),'%m')
df$day <- format(as.Date(df$DATE),'%d')
```

Output I am getting

```
55688   01  05
55688   01  06
```

Expected output

```
1962   01   01
1962   01   02
```

Comment: Try `format(as.Date(as.character(df$DATE),"%Y%m%d"),'%Y')`

Comment: Hi, I am getting this: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: What are the `class`es of you columns? Because `format(as.Date('19620101',"%Y%m%d"),"%Y")` gives me `"1962"`.

Comment: Hi, df$DATE is an integer

Comment: It seems that you can extract everything in one step  using the `tidyr` package by `df %>% extract(DATE,into=c('year','month','day'),"(....)(..)(..)")`

Comment: I got it. I have to paste it. df$year <- format(as.Date(paste(df$DATE),'%Y%m%d'),'%Y')

Comment: @MaratTalipov Thanks. I wanted to avoid using too many packages.

Comment: You just need it to be `character`, which is why I used `as.character`; `paste` will do this implicitly.

Comment: If you expect the output to be an integer as well:  `as.numeric(substr(as.character(x),0,4))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [lubridate package](http://cran.rstudio.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html).

```
library("lubridate")
d <- ymd("19620101")
year(d)
month(d)
day(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just substring?

```
substring(as.character(19620101), 1, 4)
substring(as.character(19620101), 5, 6)
substring(as.character(19620101), 7, 8)
```

Comment: `substring` is vectorised and does not complain with non-character, so, in a step, `substring(19620101, c(1, 5, 7), c(4, 6, 8))`